# Power BI iframe Stealing page focus

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, powerbi

I'm trying to embed a Power BI published report in my web app using an iframe like this:

`<iframe width="933" height="700" src="my url" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>`

but when the page loads, the page autofocus to the Power BI iframe..

I tried many scripts of scrolling the window back to page top or using the onload attribute too but in vain!

So, any idea how to resolve this ?

I'm using Chrome browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered me till now, I used this walkaround for the time being:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-Embedded-Stealing-Focus/m-p/239953